# creation time is invalid when update in yii2

Tags: yii2

when I want to update form in yii2

It tells me this error

> creation time is invalid -- update time is invalid

What do you think is it?

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    $date = new \DateTime();
    $date->setTimestamp(time());
    $date->setTimezone(new \DateTimezone('Istanbul'));
    $this->update_time = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    if($this->isNewRecord)
        $this->creation_time = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```

**My problem has been resolved**

change date to safe in rules

```
   [['creation_time', 'update_time'], 'safe'],
```

Comment: show the exact error message  ..  the error  comes from an exception ? form a validation rules?  ...

Comment: error is sent from the form validation

Comment: then update  your question and  add your validation rules  for this model

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct "Nader" but some time assigning the value not work so just remove the value or use this

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'createdAtAttribute' => 'create_time',
            'updatedAtAttribute' => 'update_time',
            //'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
        ],
    ];
}
```

Just comment the value,
it will work.
For more detail https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-behaviors-timestampbehavior

Answer (score 1):

Just could just use the available [TimestampBehavior](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-behaviors-timestampbehavior) behavior

```
   use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
   use yii\db\Expression;
   use yii\db\ActiveRecord;


   class Mymodel extends ActiveRecord{

     public function behaviors() {
           return  [
             [
              'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
              'createdAtAttribute' => 'creation_time',
              'updatedAtAttribute' => 'update_time',
              'attributes' => [
                 ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'creation_time',
                 ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'update_time',
              ],
              'value' => new Expression('NOW()')
            ]
          ];
      }
   }
```

Remove any validation rules from your model you may have for this two attributes
`creation_time` and `update_time`